# How to keep lookup tables initialized for prediction (and not just training)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I create a lookup table from [`tf.contrib.lookup`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup), using the training data (as input). Then, I pass every input through that lookup table, before passing it through my model.

This works for training, but when it comes to online prediction from this same model, it raises the error:

> Table not initialized

I'm using `SavedModel` to save the model. I run the prediction from this saved model.

How can I initialize this table so that it stays initialized? Or is there a better way to save the model so that the table is always initialized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify an "initialization" operation when you add a meta graph to your SavedModel bundle with [`tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder#add_meta_graph), using the `main_op` or `legacy_init_op` kwarg. You can either use a single operation, or group together a number of operations with `tf.group` if you need more than one.

Note that in Cloud ML Engine, You'll have to use the `legacy_init_op`. However in future `runtime_version`s you will be able to use `main_op` 
(IIRC, starting with `runtime_version == 1.2`)

The saved_model module provides a built in [`tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/main_op/main_op)  to wrap up common initialization actions in a single op (local variable initialization, and table initialization).

So in summary, code should look like this (adapted from [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/tensorflowcore/trainer/task.py#L321)):

```
  exporter = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(
      os.path.join(job_dir, 'export', name))

  # signature_def gets constructed here

  with tf.Session(graph=prediction_graph) as session:
    # Need to be initialized before saved variables are restored
    session.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
    # Restore the value of the saved variables
    saver.restore(session, latest)
    exporter.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        session,
        tags=[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY: signature_def
        },
        # Relevant change to the linked example is here!
        legacy_init_op=tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op()
    )
```

NOTE: If you are using the high level libraries (such as [`tf.estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/estimator)) this should be the default, and if you need to specify additional initialization actions you can specify them as part of the [`tf.train.Scaffold`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/Scaffold) object that you pass to your [`tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EstimatorSpec) in your model_fn.

Comment: What do you mean by  `If you are using the high level libraries (such as tf.estimator) this should be the default`? How can I pass my custom `init_op` upon constructing estimator?

Answer (score 14):

I think you would be better off using `tf.tables_initializer()` as the `legacy_init_op`.

`tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op()` also adds local and global initialization ops in addition to table initialization.
when you load the saved model and it runs the `legacy_init_op`, it would reset your variables, which is not what you want.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer.  "tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op" seems not work well, and makes result random