# tf.keras custom layer requiring initialization fails to save with tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to implement a custom lookup layer which converts strings to `ints`. I need to save the model in a tensorflow serving format. The model requires a lookup table which needs to be initialized. In the custom layer build definition the table is initialized using the `tf.keras.backend.get_session() session`. This trains fine, but when saving with `tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model` it throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot use the given session to execute operation: the operation's graph is different from the session's graph.
```

The following code reproduces the error:
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf

```
class LookupLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, mapping=[''], num_oov_buckets=0, default_value=-1, **kwargs):
    self.mapping=mapping
    self.num_oov_buckets=num_oov_buckets
    self.default_value=default_value
    super(LookupLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.index_table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
                    mapping=self.mapping,
                    num_oov_buckets=self.num_oov_buckets,
                    default_value=self.default_value,
                )
    self.index_table.init.run(session=tf.keras.backend.get_session())
    super(LookupLayer, self).build(input_shape)

  def call(self, input):
    return self.index_table.lookup(input)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape

input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
lookup_output = LookupLayer(mapping=['test'], num_oov_buckets=1)(input)
emb_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2, 1)(lookup_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(emb_layer)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss='binary_crossentropy')

X={'input_1':np.array(['test', 'oov'])}
y=[0,1]
model.fit(X,y)

tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model(model, './saved_model_test/', custom_objects={'LookupLayer': LookupLayer})
```

How do I get the right session to the custom `tf.keras` layer? Or is there a better way to do this?

note: I need the string -> int lookup to be in the graph. I can't have it in a separate preprocessing step because I need it to be there for serving.

Comment: Did you try simply not to call init? Keras will probably handle this.

Comment: I tried this and got a new error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Model and clone must use the same variables.`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to save the model to a pb file for serving by using simple_save instead of save_keras_model:

`tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    keras.backend.get_session(),
    './simple_save/',
    inputs={t.name.split(':')[0]:t for t in model.input},
    outputs={t.name.split(':')[0]:t for t in model.outputs},
    legacy_init_op=tf.tables_initializer())`

Note: make sure to use legacy_init_op=tf.tables_initializer() and NOT legacy_init_op=tf.saved_model.main_op.main_op() like the answer in [How to keep lookup tables initialized for prediction (and not just training)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236090/how-to-keep-lookup-tables-initialized-for-prediction-and-not-just-training) suggests. Otherwise it seems all weights get reset and your model is useless for serving.

This does not fix the problem I made this post for (save_keras_model not working), but it solves my use case.